# Stardict, Goldend, Abiword

Tags: dictionary

I downloaded Stardict and Goldendict. Now I want to create my english-serbian dictionary from the pdf dictionary which I downloaded from the internet. I used Abiword to convert pdf to html and then Libreoffice to convrt html to docx. When I type "stardict-editor" in the Terminal and it opens I get always this:

```
Building...
Error, no new line at the end.
Failed!
```

I googled and I saw that the problem is solved by changing http to https in goldendict. But that is the solution for the wikipedia dictionary and I want to have my new english-serbian dictionary.

So, my problem is that I cant see my dictionary in goldendict, thats because I cant "compile" in the stardict editor...

I hope you understand my question...Sorry for my bad english..

Thanks.